# Matplotlib basemap drawcoastlines() also draws a straight line

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am plotting a spatial temperature profile on top of a 'nsper' projection as shown in the figures and code below. To reduce the problem I have removed the plotting of the temperature data. For some values of lat_0 and lon_0, m.drawcoastlines() generate an additional straight line (I have marked this with a larger line-width) in the left part of the figure. For example, with lon_0 = 0 there is a straight line in the plot.

[image: picture with error2]
[image: picture with error2]
[image: picture without errors]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

m = Basemap(projection='nsper', lat_0=0, lon_0=0)

m.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 3)
m.drawcountries()

#x,y = m(lons,lats)
#m.pcolor(x,y,average[years[yr],:,:], vmin = -5, vmax = 10, cmap='jet')

#plt.colorbar()
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the plotting to cartopy and it worked.